# SQL: why I get different values for these queries that should be the same? (left join vs. not in)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have to find the values in one table that are not in another table column. This is AWS Athena (Presto is the query engine).

I did this which I believe should work:

```
select count(*) cnt
from all_users m left join login_activity a
on m.user_id = a.userid
where a.userid is null;
-- count is 1,424,527
```

I was expecting that this result would be the same

```
select count(*) cnt 
from all_users 
where user_id not in (select distinct userid from login_activity);
-- count is 1,423,447
```

My main question is: are either of these approaches better or more accurate than the other?

The count differs by around 1,000. Why would this be?

Comment: The difference is explained by a one-to-many join. A user_id can have more than one row in login_activity, right? That would explain why the first query returns a higher count. Use the 2nd query or a similar version of it.

Comment: That's right - there are many user_ids in login_activity. Thanks.